Markov Inequality example behaves unexpectly with the same gap
The Markov Inequality:
$$ 
P(X \geq c) \leq \frac{E(X)}{c}
$$
Example 1: let's say $E(X) = 10$, $c = 20$, according to Markov inequality, $P(X \geq 20) \leq \frac{10}{20} = \frac{1}{2}$.
Example 2: Considering shifting all the data on the right with 10,000 units. $E(X)$ so that to be $10,010$. with the same gap in the example, we set $c = 10,020$, according to Markov inequality, $P(X \geq c) \leq \frac{10,010}{10,020} \approx 1$
Question: Both the examples have the same gap (10), why does the upper bound show quite a different way? Is the Markov inequality better when $E(X)$ is small?

This inequality is valid for a nonnegative-valued random variable $X$.
If the mean of $X$ is 10, I would expect the event $\{X\ge20\}$ not to happen too often because it contributes to values significantly higher than the mean, and there is not that much room between 0 and 10 to compensate.
If the mean of $X$ is 10010, I would not expect that much constraint on the event $\{X\ge10020\}$, as there is plenty of room between 0 and 10010 to compensate.
Markov's inequality gives more information when $c$ is big comparatively to the mean, that is if $c$ is much biger than $\mathbb E[X]$. In your first example, 20 is the double of 10, but 10020 is only around 0.1% more than 10010. When $c$ is much bigger than $\mathbb E[X]$ then $\frac{\mathbb E[X]}{c}$ is small and the inequality is informative.

In the case where $E(X)=10$ and $a=20$, the gap of $10$ is much more significant because it's literally one time the expectation. So a value that would be above $20$ would be twice the expectation.
In the case where $E(X)=10,010$ and $a=10,020$, the same gap is very small compared to the expectation, which results in almost no additional information using Markov inequality.
In a sense, this inequality is converting the information of the ratio (not the difference) of the expectation and a given constant $c$ into a bound for the cumulative distribution function of a random variable.
To sum up a bit, when you compare the same $10$ difference gap between $E(X)$ and $c$ on these two cases, you are thinking implicitly about the notion of deviation, which is not present inside Markov inequalities, in which only the ratio between $E(X)$ and $c$ matters.
So yes, in this sense, for a constant gap between $E(X)$ and $c$, Markov inequality works betters for a low expectation.

One of the standard proofs of Markov's inequality is the following
\begin{align}
   \mathbb{E}[X]
   &= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X < c) + X\cdot \pmb{1}(X \geq c)] \\
   &= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] + \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X \geq c)] \\
   &\geq \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] + \mathbb{E}[c\cdot \pmb{1}(X \geq c)] \\
   &= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] + c\mathbb{E}[\cdot \pmb{1}(X \geq c)] \\
   &= \mathbb{E}[X\cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] + c \mathbb{P}(X \geq c) \\
\end{align}
Rearranging this gives the improved Markov's inequality
\begin{equation}
    \mathbb{P}(X \geq c) \leq \frac{1}{c} \left ( \mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] \right )
\end{equation}
To recover the standard Markov inequality one uses that $X \geq 0$ and therefore
$$\mathbb{E}[X] - \mathbb{E}[X \cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)] \leq \mathbb{E}[X]$$
However, this can be incredibly loose when $\mathbb{E}[X \cdot \pmb{1}(X < c)]$ is large compared to $\mathbb{E}[X]$.
In your first example the standard form of Markov's inequality is about as good as the improved form, while in the second example the improved form is going to be much better.
